# How to refresh the Label one by one?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, label

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Methode met = new Methode();

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Label Example");
    JLabel l1;
    JButton btn;
    l1 = new JLabel("Start", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    btn = new JButton("Bestätigen");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    String comboBoxListe[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }; // 1=300 2=250 3=200 4=150 5=100
    JComboBox bundeslandAuswahl = new JComboBox(comboBoxListe);
    panel.add(bundeslandAuswahl);
    l1.setBounds(0, 0, 1800, 800);
    l1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 100));
    btn.setBounds(800, 0, 100, 50);
    panel.setBounds(900, 0, 100, 100);
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            met.ausgabe(l1);
        }
    });
    f.add(btn);
    f.add(l1);
    f.add(panel);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    Timer t = new Timer();

}}

class Methode {

void ausgabe(JLabel l1) {
    String temp = "";
    String[] arr2 = { "Hallo", "World", "!" };
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {

        temp = arr2[i];

        l1.setText(temp);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(800);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

The Label only shows the last element of the Array, if i use the ActionListener. Without the btn.addActionListener its work. How can i solve it with a button? I want that when I click the method **ausgabe**, that the code displays step by step the individual array fields in the label.

Thanks

Comment: Start by looking at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the reasons why this approach won't work and then [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the solution

Comment: You're also going to have issues with your container hierarchy and layouts

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you have to repaint the component(l1). When you use graphic user interface in a single thread program, your program will run into a while block within the GUI code. So when the part of the code that is being executed is not yours then the program is working in GUI staff like repainting the window or graphic components.
You have to call a method in l1 to repaint it. That's the reason because the last text is the only showed. In that way a GUI code will be executed and your interface will be updated. If you do that your problem will be solved. Use the java documentation to find this method.

Comment: can you maybe tell me how and where to add the repaint?

Comment: No, you don't.  `setText` of `JLabel` is a bound property, which means it will trigger it's own update

Comment: @R0land01 Except, the `for-loop` is been called within the Event Dispatching Thread, which means that until the method exits, the EDT won't process any new paint events, so, even if it were required, it still wouldn't work

Comment: @MadPgrogrammer You are right. The EDT will not pay attention to other events.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the reasons why this approach won't work and then [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the solution.

The "core" issue is, Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.  This means that when you call `ausgabe` from the `ActionListener`, you're trying to run a long running/blocking process within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

But, until the method exists, the EDT can not process any new paint or other events, so nothing gets updated until it's completed.

Because Swing is also not thread safe, it's not advisable to use a `Thread` to try and fix the issue.  Instead, you should make use of a Swing `Timer`, which acts like a pseudo loop, but which is called back within the EDT, making it safe to use to update the UI.

## For example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private Timer timer;
        private String text = "Hello World";

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("");
            add(label);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.stop();
                timer = null;
            }

            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                private int counter;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    if (counter >= text.length()) {
                        timer.stop();
                        timer = null;
                    }
                    label.setText(text.substring(0, counter));
                    counter += 1;
                }

            });
            timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.stop();
                timer = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }
}
```

You should also take the time to learn how to use the various layout managers, it will save you a lot of time, hassle and head scratching.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

One trick I might have used, would have been to use two labels.  One with the full text set on it and with it's text color set the same color as the background of the panel, the second used to animate the update.  Each positioned so that they will overlap each other.

This way, you provide enough information to the layout manager to make determinations about how much space the component needs.

In the above example, I just cheated and overrode `getPreferredSize`, again, this could have just calculated the final size of the label, but that's becoming complicated.